# Anonymous-ish classes (closure?) in Swift for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

#### Some context:

I've been away from iOS programming for 5+ years and boy howdy have things changed. Just to make it more exciting, I'm trying Swift at the same time.

I'm trying to build a relatively simple iOS app using the Master-Detail App template and am at the point where I'm trying to add sections to the data. My (Core Data) data model is pretty simple at this point - some `Location`s (these are the sections) each of which contain some `Container`s. These are linked in the obvious way (a `Location` have a one-to-many reference to `Container`s, and `Container`s have a one-to-one reference to its `Location`).

I suspect that I'm heading to a place where I'm going to want the `fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)` to return the `Container` corresponding with the `indexPath` but I'm also going to want the `fetchedResultsController.sections[section]` to return a `Location`.

#### The code

This is pretty much the code that comes from the app template (with minor modifications to use my `Location` type as the generic `ResultType` for `NSFetchedResultsController` - that might might be a mistake; maybe it should be a `Container` or even a `NSManagedObject` - we'll get to that in a minute).

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Location> {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Location> = Location.fetchRequest()

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        do {
            try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
        } catch {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             let nserror = error as NSError
             fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
```

#### My questions

I'm new to Swift and I'm struggling to understand what the code that the Xcode template created for me. So I have a few questions:

1. What do we call this pattern? Anonymous classes (apparently not)? Closures? Knowing what it's called will help me do a better job of searching for related answers instead of wasting your time on these noob questions.
2. What is it actually defining? What I suspect it's doing is defining an implementation for `init` and returning an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` that has all the default implementations. If that's not completely right, help me understand it a little better (pointing at something to read is also helpful).
3. How should I go about overriding methods of `NSFetchedResultsController` when using this pattern? Or is that something where I need to create a *real* subclass.
4. What type should I be using as the generic `ResultType` and why? This is a little off topic, but what the heck, maybe you'll take pity on me and bump me along another step of the journey.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's basically called a *computed property*.
2. It checks if an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` exists. If not it creates one and configures it.
3. There is nothing to override. However you should implement the delegate methods.
4. The generic type is correct. It avoids a lot of type casting.

I doubt this is the code which *comes from the app template*. The Swift equivalent of the *objective-c-ish* pattern with the instance variable and the nil-check is a lazy instantiated property. The body is called once the first time the property is accessed.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<Location> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Location> = Location.fetchRequest()

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    controller.delegate = self

    do {
        try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         let nserror = error as NSError
         fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }

    return controller
}()
```

To add sections you have to specify the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter and add an appropriate second sort descriptor.

The table view data source methods should look like

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian. It really is the code from the template (I changed references to `Event` to `Location`.

Comment: > However you should implement the delegate methods. 
Where do I do this? In the class that holds this property?

Comment: Yes, in the class which represents `self`